# redux-thunk: actions are not dispatching

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to build an app in react native that is suppose to take take two inputs by a user and then make a query to an api and get information about the two inputs. I have been having trouble with redux and redux-thunk and specifically with async actions.

This is the code in my app that i am specifically having trouble with

```
export const fetchData = url => {
  console.log("start Fetching");
  return async dispatch => { // this is where the problem is
    dispatch(fetchingRequest());
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10");
      const json = await response.text();
      if (response.ok) {
        dispatch(fetchingSuccess(json));
        console.log("JSON", json);
      } else {
        console.log("fetch did not resolve");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(fetchingFailure(error));
    }
  };
  console.log("Fetched data");
};
```

Upon debugging the function, I have ended with finding that when the fetchData function is called the function will execute but the async dispatch that is being returned has undefined behavior.

The output in the debugger when the function is called should be

```
start Fetching
JSON file information/Error
```

but the output in the debugger is actually

```
start Fetching
```

This is the function in which `fetchData` is called in

```
_onPress = () => {
    let url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10";
    fetchData(url);
    console.log("should have fetched");
  };
```

this is the `mapDispatchToProps` function that I have added. The problem is i do not know what to add inside the function.

```
const mapStatetoDispatch = (url, dispatch) => {
  return {dispatch(fetchData(url))}; // do not know what to place in body of function

};
```

i have connected it in the component with

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

these are the action creators that I import, if needed

```
import {
  fetchingSuccess,
  fetchingRequest,
  fetchingFailure,
  fetchData
} from "../data/redux/actions/appActions.js";
```

Comment: try fetchData(url)(); But you will have to connect it with react-redux because fetchData doesn't know what dispatch is.

Comment: do u mean with a `mapDispatchToProps` function and if so is there anyway that you can make an answer for it.

Comment: Do you have a repo for this?

Comment: I am building this app for someone else and I am not allowed to share the repo. I have edited the post to reflect what the problem is. I am now just confused about what to place in the `mapDispatchToProps` function to make the `dispatch` to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have added redux-thunk as a middleware, it looks like the errors are here:

```
_onPress = () => {
  const { fetchData } = this.props;
    let url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10";
    fetchData(url);
    console.log("should have fetched");
  };
```

and

```
const mapStatetoDispatch = dispatch => ({
  fetchData: url => dispatch(fetchData(url)),
}};
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem and not the function itself.